Slow wifi signal with TP Link WN725N v3 Ubuntu 24.04
I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 24.04, and I'm having a problem with the wifi speed. I use TP Link WN725N v3, and the wifi connection is extremely slow. In Windows wifi worked perfect.
How can I fix it?
Results of iwconfig :*
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
wlxd0374521be15  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Nursultan"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: F8:F0:82:A4:69:53   
          Bit Rate=19.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0

